# env: python2.7: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, dreal

I tried to install dreal following the instructions in https://pypi.org/project/dreal/. But it failed. The error is 'env: python2.7: No such file or directory'.

I guess it is an error related to the Mac OS Monterey?

Any help would be appreciated! If I missed or forgot anything please let me know, I'm quite new to this.

I tried to install python2.7 on my mac. But it didn't work.

Comment: did you try using ```pip3 install dreal``` to install it? if not what did you use?

Comment: yes, i use pip3.

Comment: the error occurred, when i typed this 'brew install dreal --only-dependencies'

Comment: what about building it from source? ```/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dreal/dreal4/master/setup/mac/install.sh | bash
dreal```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this. but it still shows the same error.

Comment: You should install Python 3.7 based on the package documentation and not Python 2.7

N-B: In general, you should avoid old python version: you can check https://endoflife.date/python to see which version to install

N-B: (`pip3` is a python 3 command, so it is not surprising it does not work with Python 2)

Comment: Sorry. But i am using python 3.7 now. Also, I can use pip3 to install dreal. The error appeared when I tried this command 'brew install dreal --only-dependencies'.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, dReal doesn’t support M1/M2 macs. You need to use either an intel Mac or a Linux machine with x86_64 CPUs.